# assigning java images to different instances of objects (playing cards)

Tags: java

I'm trying to write an applet to display packs of cards amongst other things.

I have a folder with 52 card images in.

How would I go about assigning an image to each instance of a Card object?

Would I need to create a 52 image array within the object and then assign the right index to each card?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What stops you from creating a field, `image`, containing an image (instance of `java.awt.Image` or whatever you use for your UI) itself?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that a card should be an immutable object.
As such, I would define the image for a Card on construction of the Card:

eg:

```
public class Card {
    final int value;
    final Suit suit;
    final BufferedImage image;

    public Card(int value, Suit suit) throws IOException {
        this.value = value;
        this.suit = suit;
        File imageFile = new File("image-dir", suit + "-" + value + ".jpg");
        this.image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
    }

    public enum Suit {
        Spades, Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts;
    }
}
```

You could then populate a deck like this:

```
Set<Card> deck = new HashSet<Card>();
for (int value = 1 ; value <= 13 ; value++) {
    for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
        deck.add(new Card(value, suit));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [enums](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html)? You could add a `getImage()` method to the `Card` class that returns the correct image based on the card's `Rank` and `Suite`. That would of course imply a consistent naming convention of the image files, e.g.

```
private static final String IMAGE_DIR = // image directory

public BufferedImage getImage() {
    String fileName = suite + "_" + rank + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(IMAGE_DIR, fileName);
    return ImageIO.read(file);
}
```

You should also consider to cache the images so that you do not read the images from file every time they are needed.